# Alias dota2 to the existing tag dota-2

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I'm not really sure how this should be done, but it's far more common for people to refer to the game as Dota2 than anything else, and so having this automatically redirect to the existing dota-2 tag would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds reasonable enough. Done!